# Image Upload HTTP error Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

When I upload the image in the wordpress,I get the HTTP error.Though images are inserted in upload folder.Yet it shows the error.

I have tried with the .htaccess work
..
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
..
but didnt work.I also tried with permission for the uploads folder issue.
I dont have any error in the debug.log just few of the PHP Notice
I have wordpress 3.3,windows with the apache server.

Answer (score 2):

Just try to add below code theme’s functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'change_graphic_lib' );
    function change_graphic_lib($array) {
    return array( 'WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick' );
}
```

for more ways to solve this problem visit this link [HOW TO FIX HTTP ERROR WHEN UPLOADING IMAGES](https://elitedigi.com/how-to-fix-http-error-when-uploading-images/)

Answer (score 1):

Installing the "Default to GD" plugin which "Sets GD as default WP_Image_Editor class."

The plugin is (currently) available here: https://github.com/getsource/default-to-gd/blob/master/default-to-gd.php

It's has function:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Default to GD
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/default-to-gd
Description: Sets GD as default WP_Image_Editor class.
Author: Mike Schroder
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://www.getsource.net/
*/
function ms_image_editor_default_to_gd( $editors ) {
    $gd_editor = 'WP_Image_Editor_GD';
    $editors = array_diff( $editors, array( $gd_editor ) );
    array_unshift( $editors, $gd_editor );
    return $editors;
}
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'ms_image_editor_default_to_gd' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload the image via File-Zilla or other ftp solutions instead of the build-in utility?

only a suggestion.

Comment: i tried that too the images are uploaded but yet it isnt displayed in the media library

Comment: that's because they are not uploaded to the wp-database. How big are the images? For what do you use them?

Comment: Images are around 25kb.It is used for the featured image.I have worked with the static url images but can be used only inside the editor

Comment: Maybe this page will help you with the problem that the image isn't displayed in the media library: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/files-ftpd-to-the-wordpress-upload-folder-arent-viewable-manageuploads-tab?replies=8

Comment: or add the image directly in the page or site editor, not with the wp-uploader.

Comment: if you have some plugin related to image manipulation, disable it and check it again.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.
The problem was with the Wordfence plugin firewall. I turned it to "learning mode" and the upload worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work for me.
My solution (for CentOS and php in FastCGI mode):

1) Open /etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf

2) Add or change a values for the following parameters:

```
FcgidConnectTimeout 20
MaxRequestLen 64000000
FcgidMaxRequestLen 64000000
```

3) restart apache

```
apachectl restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ubuntu and wasn't able to upload images (`http error`) to a wordpress site in my localhost. In my case I tried uploading to meida via explorer (not drag and drop) I saw that I **wasn't able to access** that location (in my external hard disk.

**So I copied the file to the desktop and was able to load it without any issue.**