# Cannot increase maximum upload file size in local WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, upload

I am using my own **localhost** (ubuntu and apache2) for running wordpress 4.8 . I want to increase maximum upload file size. I tried these ways but didn't solve :

1.creating `php.ini` in `/var/www/html` or changing it in `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`:

```
upload_max_filesize = 512M
memory_limit = 512M
post_max_size = 512M
max_execution_time = 300
```

2.changing `.htaccess` in `/var/www/html`:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 512M
php_value post_max_size 512M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

3.adding these line of codes in `functions.php` file in the theme folder:

```
@ini_set('upload_max_size' , '512M');
@ini_set('post_max_size', '512M');
@ini_set('max_execution_time', '300');
```

4.using [Upload Max File Size plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/upload-max-file-size/). this plugin changed `Maximum upload file size: 2 MB.` message but after uploading file more than 2mb the `HTTP error.` accrued. (for fixing this i also tried every solution i found on web (ex: [+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091063/wordpress-http-error-when-uploading-files),[+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525896/image-upload-http-error-wordpress),[+](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59763/how-to-fix-http-error-when-uploading-images?rq=1)) but nothing changed. also turning on wordpress log cant help me. there wasn't anything!! So i gave up. i think the root of this error is bad fix for this problem)

5.changing permissions of all files and folder to 777.

6.after every fix i tried, i also restart apache but nothing changed:

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Did you really created a `php.ini`?

Comment: there isn't `php.ini` in `/var/www/html/`. but i found `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` in phpinfo  @ankit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shouldn't create any `php.ini` file in `/var/www/html/`. I found `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` path in `phpinfo()` details. So i found and changed these configs in this file : `upload_max_filesize`, `memory_limit`, `post_max_size` and `max_execution_time`.

> NOTE: I was right! `HTTP error.` while uploading media was because of
>   bad fix for this problem. now i can upload any media correctly :)

Comment: Attention! Be careful! 

"Memory_limit" should have the largest number of megabytes. The next is "max_file_uploads", after which is "post_max_size", and last the "upload_max_filesize".

Answer (score 6):

Go to C:/Xampp/php/php.ini and find:

```
memory_limit=.....M
```

Change it to:

```
memory_limit=10000M
```

Then scroll down to:

```
post_max_size=.....M
```

And change it to:

```
post_max_size=9999M
```

Find:

```
file_uploads=...
```

If it's of write:

```
file_uploads=On
```

Scroll down and find

```
upload_max_filesize=....M
```

Write there:

```
upload_max_filesize=9000M
```

Also find:

```
max_file_uploads=.....
```

And write there:

```
max_file_uploads=10000M
```

Attention! Be careful! "Memory_limit" should have the largest number of megabytes. The next is "max_file_uploads", after which is "post_max_size", and last the "upload_max_filesize".

If there is still the same error, make your .htaccess like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /your_site_name/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /your_site_name/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
    # WP Maximum Execution Time Exceeded
    <IfModule mod_php7.c>
    php_value max_execution_time 300

    php_value upload_max_filesize 9000M
    php_value post_max_size 9999M
    php_value max_input_time 300

    </IfModule>
```

Comment: i am using Ubuntu :|

Comment: Oh, that's for xampp

Comment: Is the xampp app there the same?1

Comment: Yes, tge solution is the same @atanas

Answer (score 4):

You can change these lines on your `php.ini` file of currently running php version.

```
Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 256M
```

Comment: Make sure memory limit has a bigger number than upload max file size! Else it will bug.

Answer (score 2):

you need also to add this filter to the functions.php file to see the allowed upload in your Wordpress , its good to not use plugin :)

```
//filter
add_filter('upload_size_limit', 'increase_upload');
function increase_upload($bytes) {
    return 262144000;
}
```